# C# XDocument.Load could not find file?

Tags: c#

I have the following logic in a controller

```
public void Makes() {
            // iterate over makes.xml
            XDocument myDoc = XDocument.Load("makes.xml");
            var make = myDoc.Descendants("make");
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in make)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
    }
```

And I get the following error

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\makes.xml'.'

I have the needed file here:
[image]

How can I get it to pass into the load function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[`Server.MapPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx)** to get the path to your file

```
Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/makes.xml")
```

Comment: Server does not exist in this current context. I included `system.web`

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath